# Print user information from database table according to username

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a login form and I'm trying to print in a JSP the user's information from database, according to the username filled.

I have a DAO class for database connection which I imported to my JSP. These are the variables:

```
        public Connection connection;
        public PreparedStatement statement;
        public ResultSet rs;
```

In JSP, I created a variable to retrieve the value of Username filled in login form and made a simple query to fetch all information about the user in my table userinfo:

```
String n1 = request.getParameter("username");
String query = "select * from userinfo where username = ?";
```

This is the rest of my JSP and I'm trying to set the value of my query according to n1 value (username filled by the user) to then print all the info from table userinfo about the specific user:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     dao.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dao.url, dao.user, dao.pass);
     dao.statement = dao.connection.prepareStatement(query);
     dao.statement.setString(1, n1 );
     dao.rs = dao.statement.executeQuery(query);
     while(dao.rs.next()){
         
         %>
         <tr>
            <td><%= dao.rs.getString(1) %></td>
            <td><%= dao.rs.getString(2) %></td>
            <td><%= dao.rs.getString(3) %></td>
         </tr>
         <%
```

Can anyone guide me? I don't have any problems in fetching the values from database with a query bellow (for example) but I only want to retrieve information about the user logged.

```
String query = "select * from userinfo";
```

Comment: why you have `dao.statement.executeUpdate();` and `dao.statement.executeQuery(query);` together ?

Comment: thanks for noticing it since I only need executeQuery() here. Will edit in the original post. Still can't get n1 value to the query.

Comment: Print and see if `n1` has any value or not

Comment: it wasn't printing any value like it was, but even with a request.getparameter() which is printing the username value, I can't: String n1 = request.getParameter("username");

Comment: I will edit the post with the updated code for easier understanding as well.

Comment: Your code seems ok to me . Maybe problem is somewhere else are you sure you are running above code only ?

Comment: I think it's on the query itself since I am getting this error: 

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?'

Comment: Answering to the other part of your question, I have two filters: one to record log info into the database (which i'm using another prepareStatement() )  and another to do the authentication comparing the login credentials with the values on the database. And of course the login form on JSP. Do you think it's because i'm already using a prepareStatement() already?

Comment: Got it change this to  `dao.statement.executeQuery(query)`  to `dao.statement.executeQuery()` because you have already passed `query` while preparing statement

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much sir, have a great day! Cheers

Comment: @Sousam - Swati is a girl . It's an Indian name.